# AttributeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

I got an error,AttributeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'objects'.
I wanna parse excel and put it to the model(City&Prefecture&Area&User) . I wrote

```
user3 = User.objects.filter(corporation_id=val3).first()
if user3:
   area = Area.objects.filter(name="America").first()
   pref = Prefecture.objects.create(name="prefecture", area=user3.area)
   city = City.objects.create(name="city", prefecture=pref)
   price_u1000 = Price.upper1000.objects.get(city=city)
   price_500_1000 = Price.from500to1000.objects.get(city=city)
   price_u500 = Price.under500.objects.get(city=city)

   pref.name = "NY"
   pref.save()

   for i in range(2,len(fourrows_transpose)):
       city.name = fourrows_transpose[i][1]
       city.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][1])

       price_u1000.name = fourrows_transpose[i][2]
       price_u1000.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][2])

       price_500_1000.name = fourrows_transpose[i][3]
       price_500_1000.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][3])

       price_u500.name = fourrows_transpose[i][4]
       price_u500.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][4])
```

Traceback says this code `price_u1000 = Price.upper700.objects.get(city=city)` is wrong.
models.py is

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='area', null=True)
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area',null=True, blank=True)

class Prefecture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='prefecture')
    area = models.ForeignKey('Area', null=True, blank=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='city')
    prefecture = models.ForeignKey('Prefecture', null=True, blank=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    upper1000 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='u1000', null=True)
    from500to1000 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='500～1000', null=True)
    under500 = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='d500', null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', null=True, blank=True)
```

What should I do to fix this?How should I write it?

Answer (score 2):

Its because upper1000 or what ever field does not have the attribute objects. objects is present in the Model class.

Well if upper1000, from500to1000 and under500 is mutually exclusive you could do something like this. But remember if this is the case you should handle mutually exclusiveness in the models clean function.

```
price_u1000 = Price.objects.filter(city=city, upper1000__isnull=False, from500to1000__isnull=True, under500__isnull=True)
```

I would recommend to create a choice field instead of 3 different fields which seems to be mutually exclusive

```
class Price(models.Model):

    UNDER_500 = 'under 500'
    FROM_500_TO_1000 = 'from 500 to 1000'
    UPPER_1000 = 'upper 1000'

    PRICE_CHOICES = [
        (UNDER_500, pgettext_lazy('Price under 500')),
        (FROM_500_TO_1000, pgettext_lazy('Price from 500 to 1000')),
        (UPPER_1000, pgettext_lazy('Price above 1000'))
    ]

    price_range = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=ugettext_lazy('Price range'),
        max_length=25,
        choices=PRICE_CHOICES,
        default=UNDER_500
    )

    city = models.ForeignKey('City', null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        super(Price, self).clean()
        # implement extra constraints here.
```

Some readings:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: thx ur comments.I did not wanna exclusive from500to1000 and under500 if upper1000.I wanna put these model to data.

Comment: Ok, but the first sentence explains your problem, and the first query is how you should query data from the model. Remember to use filter when querying such data since there is no unique=True on any of your fields other than id/pk. Therefore you'll have to expect more than one row returning from your query.